# How can I retrieve theme colors from another module and apply them to drawables?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, multi-module

I cannot retrieve colors from my theme for my shape drawable. When I use `?attr/colorPrimary`, no color is being applied, neither `?colorPrimary` or `?android:colorPrimary` works. 
 My drawable is in **Common:view** module and my theme is in **Common:ui** like the image:
 [image: Module order]

I need to switch colors between the dark and light themes. I have already tried setting a new theme in **Common:view** (the same module as my shape drawable), but it does not work.

I read that this can be fixed with 2 drawables (one for each theme), but I don't know if it's the better way to do it.

Any help is appreciated.